# Can data-transition and data-ajax be together?

Tags: ajax, forms, button, jquery-mobile

i've read this post this post [Data-transition and data-ajax together in Jqmobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943770/data-transition-and-data-ajax-together-in-jqmobile) . it says data-transition cannot be together with data-ajax=false. i used data-ajax for my forms and button so that it will display my data on the second page. but i also want to use data-transition as i want it to transit to another page with animation such as slide. What is the alternative if i want to use both?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use both together.

You do not have to put `data-ajax='false'` to display second page.

Comment: for my case, if i don't use data-ajax=false, it will not display the data.. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975064/data-does-not-display-after-navigate-page/10992543#comment14369084_10992543, but when i used data-ajax the data display.. i know i cant used both. the default page transition is fade, how could i change the default one?